# showing this message "index row requires (some large) bytes, maximum size is 8191" in postgresql

Tags: image, postgresql

I am trying to insert a query with image as binary value in postgresql, but showing this message "index row requires (some large) bytes, maximum size is 8191". The field for storing the binary value is given as text.

The code i used to compress and create binary format of the image is give below:

```
$source_img = $imgdocument["tmp_name"];
$destination_img = '../temp/cancel_doc_image_'.trim($details['val']).'_'.$key.'.jpg';
$compressed = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 10);            
$photo_get  = file_get_contents($destination_img);
list($width, $height, $image_type) = getimagesize($destination_img);
$mime_photo= image_type_to_mime_type($image_type);
$photo_en = base64_encode($photo_get);
$details['document'][$key]['imgdocument'] = data:".$mime_photo.";base64,".$photo_en;
```

The function for compression of image what is used is given below

```
function compress($source, $destination, $quality)
{
    $info = getimagesize($source);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
    {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    }   
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
    {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    }
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
    {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    }
    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
    return $destination;
}
```

Image

[image]

Comment: Storing an "image" in a `text` column is a bad choice to begin with. But why do you have an index on that column? That does not make any sense

Comment: Thank you. Got the issue. Removed the index.

Comment: use blob to store files

Comment: But there is no blob data type in postgresql

Comment: There is [`bytea`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html) to store relatively small binary data or [Large Objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html) to store anything you want.